# How to set up a server for a local wifi multiplayer game for python

Tags: python, server, multiplayer

I'm making a Cards Against Humanity game (but nicer/family friendly-er) and I have it set up where all I need to do is run player functions and then a judge function until someone wins. I recently asked another question specifically about my game, but if you know a solid foolproof way to set up a multiplayer game over local wifi, I would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: if you want, try looking into the `socket` package, although that might be a little too low level for what you want. You could also just build an http server with something like `flask`.

Comment: @MZ I was looking at that and found a tutorial video but my code didn't work, even though I followed the video exactly. If you have experience with this module maybe you could help me out.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `network zero`? It's an amazing networking library that I use all the time.

Install:

```
pip install networkzero
```

PyPI link: https://pypi.org/project/networkzero/

Docs: https://networkzero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Code sample (from their doc page):

Machine/process A:

```py
import networkzero as nw0

address = nw0.advertise("hello")
while True:
    name = nw0.wait_for_message_from(address)
    nw0.send_reply_to(address, "Hello " + name)
```

Machine/process B:

```py
import networkzero as nw0

hello = nw0.discover("hello")
reply = nw0.send_message_to(hello, "World!")
print(reply)
reply = nw0.send_message_to(hello, "Tim")
print(reply)
```

This library also supports more than just 2 connections on the local WiFi, read the docs for more info.

Comment: I copied the codes directly from the website, but the process B part never discovers the nw0.advertise('hello'). Am I doing something wrong or does it just take a really long time?

Comment: They must be on the same network, connection usually takes less than 5 seconds if done correctly

Comment: You might also have to allow access past firewalls, blah blah blah... and you might also need to have the 2 computers allow discovering of other computers in Windows settings...