# How to implement simple client-server interactions in pure python?

Tags: python, rest, http, flask, websocket

I want to implement an IoT application. I will give here a toy version of what I want to do.

Say I have two clients : 'client1' and 'client2' on REMOTE COMPUTERS, and a server 'server', that regulates the computations. The hard thing for me is the fact that the computations can't be made at the same place.

We have : `clients_list = ['client1', 'client2']`

I want to simulate an algorithm that looks like this:

The server starts with an initial value server_value

```
for round in range(R):
    client_values_dict = {}
    for client_id in clients_list:
        server broadcasts server_value to the client 'client_id' # via http
        client_value = action(server_value)  # executed on clients computer
        client broadcasts its value to the server  # via http
        at the meantime, server waits for the response
    server fills dictionary with keys clients_list, values client values obtained with 'action' :
    client_values_dict[client_id]
    server_value = aggregate(client_values_dict) # executed on server computer
```

On the client side (in client.py), I have a function:

```
import time

def action(server_value):
    time.sleep(10*random.random())
    return server_value + random.random()-0.5
```

On the server side (in server.py), I have a function:

```
def aggregate(client_values_dict):
    return sum(client_values_dict.values())/len(client_values_dict.values())
```

I want to implement that : I want to write a loop at server level that performs this. I think what I need is an API to handle client-server interactions and parallel computing.

I thought of using Flask for this but I'm afraid that the loop at server level will be blocked by the app.run(debug=True) loop, and that my code won't run until I break the app with CTRL+C.

I want the computations to be made in parallel by the two clients.

I am not familiar with web developpement, my problem might seem trivial and help is probably to be found everywhere on internet, but I don't know where to look at. Any help is cheerfully welcomed.

Here is an example ofa script that simulates what I want, but online.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import random

server_value = 0
R = 10
clients_list = ['client1', 'client2']


def action(server_value):
    time.sleep(3*random.random())
    return server_value + random.random()-0.5

def aggregate(client_values_dict):
    return sum(client_values_dict.values())/len(client_values_dict.values())

for round in range(R):
    client_values_dict = {}
    for client_id in clients_list:
        client_value = action(server_value)  # executed on clients computer
        client_values_dict[client_id] = client_value
    server_value = aggregate(client_values_dict)
    print(server_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `network zero`? It's an amazing networking library that I use all the time.

Install:

```
pip install networkzero
```

PyPI link: https://pypi.org/project/networkzero/

Docs: https://networkzero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Code sample (from their doc page):

Machine/process A:

```py
import networkzero as nw0

address = nw0.advertise("hello")
while True:
    name = nw0.wait_for_message_from(address)
    nw0.send_reply_to(address, "Hello " + name)
```

Machine/process B:

```py
import networkzero as nw0

hello = nw0.discover("hello")
reply = nw0.send_message_to(hello, "World!")
print(reply)
reply = nw0.send_message_to(hello, "Tim")
print(reply)
```

This library also supports more than just 2 connections on the local WiFi, read the docs for more info.

NOTE: I've used this answer before. You can see it here: [How to set up a server for a local wifi multiplayer game for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844934/how-to-set-up-a-server-for-a-local-wifi-multiplayer-game-for-python/62844992#62844992)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think networkzero won't work in my case, because the computations I ask for the two clients are long running task and I want the clients to do them in parallel. However, in the networkzero docs, they say : "Likewise, a message is awaited from an address and a reply must be sent before another message can be received.". I think it is not possible to do tasks in parallel. But thank you for your response and I will definitively check out networkzero for later use! :)

Comment: No problem! You can have network zero automatically send a response and use polling too though. It's somewhere in the docs...